# NGNIX server settings for laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have developed a website in laravel and I want to install it on a local machine running nginx as a web server. Here is my config file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root html;
    index index.html index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;


    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }


}
```

When I browse **http://localhost/mysite/** it runs C:/nginx/html/mysite/index.php

I want to execute C:/nginx/html/mysite/public/index.php file instead. How i can do that?

Comment: Make a new regex location block pointing to `mysite` and use the `root` directive inside it to set the new root directory.

Comment: How i can make it if i want to execute this file first   C:/nginx/html/mysite/public/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Nginx file I will assume your root directory for your project is `html` and all your Laravel files are in this directory.

If this is the case then you can either just go to `http://localhost/mysite/public` or alter your `root` directory in your Nginx configuration to `html/public`.

If that doesn't work, set `root` to the full path on your local machine to reach the public folder of your Laravel project.

**Edit**
Try:

```
root /c/nginx/html/mysite/public
```

OR

```
root C:/nginx/html/mysite/public
```

Comment: my files are  C:/nginx/html/mysite/  but i want to excute is from C:/nginx/html/mysite/public/index.php

Comment: directory index of "C:\nginx/html/mysite/" is forbidden,

Comment: Try `root html/mysite/public`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my configuration:

```
server {
    server_name      laravel.mydomain;
    root             /home/me/domain/laravel.mydomain/public/;

    location / {
        try_files    $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass                      unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info           ^(.+\.php)(/.*|$);
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include        fastcgi_params;
        internal;
    }
}
```

Just change `root` to where your `public` folder is.

`try_files` makes sure that everything is served by `index.php` which is in the `root` path when the file doesn't directly exist on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to change only one line: Looks the final code in below 

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root C:/nginx/html/mysite/public;
    index index.html index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;


    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Please look the code carefully. I have changed ony 
root html to  root C:/nginx/html/mysite/public;